# Why didn't Zoidberg die in Bender's Game?

Tags: futurama, zoidberg

In Bender's Game, when they arrive in the D&D universe, Greyfarn the Wizard explains that if they're killed in that universe, they'll be killed in the regular universe too. Later, Leegola kills the Zoidberg cave-monster (several times), mistaking him for the Tunnelling Horror.

Why wasn't Zoidberg killed in the regular universe too when they returned?

Comment: Doesn't his head survive?

Comment: Because he didn't die

Answer (score 7):

Zoidberg didn't die in the real world because **he didn't die in the fantasy realm**, as you can see from this scene near the end. He seems to get *perpetually reduced* (from a giant worm down to little more than a mobile head with legs) but at no point is he actually killed.

[image]

There's also the possibility that Greyfarn the Wizard is talking complete rubbish. Literally the next words out of his mouth are that ...

> *"Cornwood's troubles began **hundreds or perhaps millions** of years ago"*

... so he can hardly be counted on as the most reliable of sources.